# Distribution Based Mapping of Augmented (Noisy) Image and Clean image?

Tags: machine-learning, probability-distribution, denoising-autoencoder, gaussian-mixture-models, image-denoising

I have a task of training a Denoising Autoencoder which will be augmented MNIST dataset and and I have to reproduce the clean image, I have to use the ResBlocks in the Encoder(Conv Layer) as well as decoder(Conv Transpose). Before proceeding to the model building part, we will have to first map the augmented images of each label to their corresponding clean label image (as we don't have these mapping). For example I will have multiple sets of image distorted, clipped, and some noise added, and I will be mapping these images to clean labels. For this mapping, my supervisor has advised that I try to use distribution based mapping which will understand the distribution of clean and augmented images, I will be able to create such a mapping which will help in model training part.
Any advise how can I do this distribution based mapping using GMMs?